# Arabic NSString shows different letter order between Xcode debugger and log

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsstring, arabic, right-to-left

I know nothing about Arabic writing, but we need to add support for it.

I'm getting confused about the letter order. As you can see in the screenshot, the order of the characters is different depending on the display method.

In Xcode I also noticed a different letter order in the preview and in the description.

[image]

Comment: Can you include the code that initializes the string? (Copy-pasted, please, to preserve order markers.)

Comment: the input is comming from a text field

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshots have same letter order, but different layout directions, i.e. the ordering of fragments of text (e.g. words). If you remove the left-to-right fragment `12345` and the letter `z`, the string will look the same in both cases.

You can learn about the tricky bidirectional text layout in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text).

In your case, I believe that U+200F right-to-left mark as the first character of your string will fix the problem. Be careful with the editor, though. XCode editor does not support bidirectional text good enough.